# Template not being recognized in Silverstripe

Tags: php, templates, model-view-controller, silverstripe

I have no idea how my old developer did it but he was able to create a couple of custom templates that work on my website.  I'm trying to create one on my own but am not succeeding and my old developer seems to be too busy to show me how to do it.

I have the templates in /templates/Layout

My Layout (InstitutionCoursesPage.ss) has the following code:

```
<% include HeaderBar %>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    $setHasLeft(true)
    <div class="$LeftCssClass">
        <% include SideNavigation %>
        <% loop $WidgetArea(LeftSideBar) %>
        $WidgetHolder
        <% end_loop %>
    </div>
    <div class="$CenterCssClass">
        <% include PageHeader %>
        <% if $Content %>
        <article class="content typography glass">
            $Content
    <div>abc</div>
        </article>
    <% loop $DisplayCourses %>
    <% end_loop %>
        <% end_if %>
        <% include InstitutionCoursesList %>
        $PageComments
    </div>
    <% include RightSideBar %>
</div>
</div>
<% include FooterBar %>
```

The PHP file (InstitutionCoursesPage.php) that was used to create the Page Type is stored in /code/PageTypes has the following code:

```
<?php

class InstitutionCoursesPage extends Page
{

}

class InstitutionCoursesPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{

public function DisplayCourses()
{
    return Qualification::get();
}

}
```

And the file in the /templates/Includes goes by the file name: InstitutionCoursesList.ss

The Pge Type works but not the template and the templates my developer had created all work and are in the same directory as the template I made.  Not sure why mine isn't working.  I tried doing flush but no avail.

Answer (score 2):

There is a debug info possible that inserts all template's file names to the rendered output in dev mode, see our talk in 2016's StripeCon: https://speakerdeck.com/wernerkrauss/debug-silverstripe-like-a-pro#27

Basically put this in a config.yml file and flush:

```
---
Only:
  environment: 'dev'
---

SSViewer:
  source_file_comments: true
```

The output should then be something like:

[image: template comments in SilverStripe]

This way you can see if your template was picked. Also be sure you don't have a typo in your class name or template filename.

> Attention: This ruins ajax calls that output pure templated JSON

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you pasted it wrong but you having nothing your loop:

```
<% loop $DisplayCourses %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Maybe the `<% include InstitutionCoursesList %>` is suppose to go in that loop?

Comment: Even if I put something in there, it is not recognized.  I tried to add some html to the file and then did a flush and it did not appear on the page's source code.  Not sure why the file itself is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there's a lot that can go wrong here.

Firstly, provided that there are courses to display, it seems that that part of the template/controller is okay. Another thing that could go wrong is that the template is not loaded altogether. So place some text that will show no matter what (on the top of the template file for example). If that's okay, let's take a look at your template, and strip it from html:

```
<% include HeaderBar %>
$setHasLeft(true)
<% include SideNavigation %>
<% loop $WidgetArea(LeftSideBar) %>
    $WidgetHolder
<% end_loop %>
<% include PageHeader %>
<% if $Content %>
    $Content
    <% loop $DisplayCourses %>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_if %>
<% include InstitutionCoursesList %>
$PageComments
<% include RightSideBar %>
<% include FooterBar %>
```

You can see that the loop of displaycourses is conditional to there being content. If that field is empty, the IF there will not be satisfied, and it will skip displaying your courses altogether.

Could that be the problem? You can simply add some dummy content to the page to test...

Update: So that's not the problem. Now, I've also struggled with the template system of Silvertripe. Sometimes it does pick the right template, sometimes it does not. In this case, you'd expect the system to look for templates in this order:

1. InstitutionCoursesPage_index.ss (because, when nothing is defined, it uses the index method
2. InstitutionCoursesPage.ss
3. Page.ss

In your case it will probably pick page.ss. If not, you are doing something else wrong, but that would be outside the scope of this question (could be anything, then).

In such cases I resort to forcing the used template manually, by using this snippet of code in your controller:

```
    public function index() {
        //TODO: why is the normal template engine not picking it up?
        return $this->renderWith(
            array('InstitutionCoursesPage', 'Page'),
            array() //here you can add extra data that's then available to the template
        );
    }
```

If someone with a bit more knowledge of the template system could point out what the intricacies of this system are, I would be much obliged...

Comment: I did a little test.  Do you see in my code where it says "<article class="content typography">"?  It also shows up in the source code.  I added "glass" to the list of classes to make it "content typography glass".  Refreshing the page should show glass in there in the source code, but it did not.  So it's not even reading the file, regardless of whether Courses works or not (which it does because I have a drop down menu on the homepage that shows the list of courses).

Comment: It's still within the if, but okay, it seems the template is not loading. Now we are in Template inheritance country, which is a little foggy for me too. I'll update my answer